# PDFBox org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInteger cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using PDFBox 2.0.25, process document to get signature dictionaries, [example pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xddhdqn7y8jsgfb/error.pdf?dl=0)

```
try{
    doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
    doc.getSignatureDictionaries()
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

document generated by scanned, producer :

```
Foxit PhantomPDF Printer Version 6.1.0.0923
```

warn message in line `doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);`

```
Object (140:0) at offset 4039608 does not end with 'endobj' but with '0'
```

then get error in line `doc.getSignatureDictionaries();`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInteger cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm.getFields(PDAcroForm.java:378)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDFieldTree$FieldIterator.<init>(PDFieldTree.java:79)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDFieldTree$FieldIterator.<init>(PDFieldTree.java:68)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDFieldTree.iterator(PDFieldTree.java:62)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getSignatureFields(PDDocument.java:932)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getSignatureDictionaries(PDDocument.java:952)
```

why this is happening ? can a file like this be handled ?

*updated : I have tried by replacing from maven repo Apache PDFBox » 2.0.25 to Apache PDFBox » 2.0.26, still getting the same error

Comment: Please retry with 2.0.26, this was fixed at the end of 2020.

Comment: I have tried by replacing from maven repo Apache PDFBox » 2.0.25 to Apache PDFBox » 2.0.26, still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry, maybe I typed the wrong line number this morning. Now I tested with 2.0.26 and it happens. But it does work with 2.0.27 snapshot, get it here https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.27-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: LOL I see that one was fixed 6 days ago https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5509 thanks to a large scale test of gigabytes of PDFs "from the wild" by fellow committer @tim-allison

Comment: In spite of PDFBox now accepting your PDF, please be aware that the file is broken

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you very much, i have tried and it work

Comment: @mkl how can i know if the file is broken? cause the file can be opened

Comment: @blinkbink Opened with what? Opening in *dobe Reader is (unfortunatly) no indication that the PDF complies with the PDF specification... And besides also in *dobe I get errors.

Comment: *"how can i know if the file is broken?"* - in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773460/1729265) I analyzed the way the PDF is broken. As a result many PDF processors only see 2 of the 5 empty signature fields of the PDF.

Comment: @Lonzak with adobe and foxit reader can be opened and readable, no error appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The underlying issue is that there is an error in the object stream in the PDF.**

According to the PDF specification ISO 32000 (both part 1 and 2), section 7.5.7 – Object Streams –

> An object in an object stream shall not consist solely of an object reference.

But the example document shared by @blinkbink does have such objects in object stream, in particular `113 0 R` for object 140, `141 0 R` for object 157 and `179 0 R` for object 191.

As these object references are forbidden in object streams, many PDF processors parse these references as the only other type of object that starts with an integer, as a number object. For example, the object 140 is parsed as the number `113`, not as a reference to object 113 (which happens to be a form field object).

As a consequence, these PDF processors in the example document find number objects in an array which should only hold form field objects. If form field reading of these processors is not programmed defensively, you get something like the `ClassCastException` observed here.

**Thus, while PDFBox used to not be defensively programmed here, the main issue is in the PDF producer that created the PDF at hand. An issue should be filed with them.**